# FieldElement Solr

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel, elementtype, baseelementmodel

for the last few hours im trying to come up with a way to use the craft field select in combination with SOLR, all my entries are in solr and i i want to keep using that. ive made it so that solr can populate the baseModels so that isnt an issue, problem is i dont know how i can get the ID's of the solr entry's being saved by craft. and retrieved trough solr when called upon.

any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some further clarification and code samples that you are using?  It's going to be difficult to answer the way the question currently stands.